# How to install jpeglib on Windows 10

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am having 64 bit Windows 10 operating system.  I have downloaded  `jpegsr9b` library from JPEG website which is used for reading JPEG header file. I have written program in C to read JPEG file as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jpeglib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

 struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

int height,width,pixel_size,colorspace,i,j,k,res;

FILE *infile = fopen("e:/Images/im.jpg", "rb");
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
width = cinfo.output_width;
height = cinfo.output_height;

printf("\nWidth = %d",width);
printf("\nHeight = %d",height);
}
```

Then compiled as

```
gcc demo.c -ljpeg
```

But it gives error

> In file included from demo.c:2:0:
>   jpeglib.h:25:62: fatal error: jconfig.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: In the same place as where you placed `<jpeglib.h>` you must install all the other header files of the jpeg lib. You must add this path to your include [environment] variables/makefile. The compiler/linker must also know where to find jpeg.lib.

Answer (score 1):

install the binary from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm) and then include the include folder from the installation in visual studio.

for more instruction follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777306/5330223).

Comment: that's an old version and it won't work for those who want to use it with dlib libraries.

Comment: "include the include folder from the installation in visual studio" can you elaborate?